# After installing puckel/docker-airflow locally, no task instance is running and tasks get stuck forever

Tags: docker, airflow

I used this tutorial to install on my local Mac airflow with docker : http://www.marknagelberg.com/getting-started-with-airflow-using-docker/ and everything worked well. I have the UI and I can connect my dags.

However, when I trigger manually my task it is not running and I get this error message[image].

My task on the web UI: [image].

I work on a Mac and I have used this code :

```bash
docker pull puckel/docker-airflow
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /path/to/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

Does someone have an idea on how I could fix this ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the airflow scheduler running? 
The airflow webserver can only show the dags & task status. The scheduler run the tasks accordingly.

for the command your showed above, there is no call for airflow scheduler.

So, you can run below command in another console.

```
docker ps |grep airflow
```

Use above command to get the container id.

```
docker exec -it [container ID] airflow scheduler
```

For the ultimate way, I suugested to use docker-compose

Comment: Thanks for your help. However after launching the `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /path/to/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver` and `docker exec [the container id]  puckel/docker-airflow webserver` I get this error. OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"puckel/docker-airflow\": stat puckel/docker-airflow: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: pls use the revised command : docker exec -it [container ID] airflow scheduler

Comment: I got the same error message `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"puckel/docker-airflow\": stat puckel/docker-airflow: no such file or directory": unknown`

Comment: pls get the container id , and run the command: docker exec -it [container ID] airflow scheduler.  I noticed that you feedback is same as last time, that means you use the old comand. pls use new command as provided

Answer (score 1):

Instead of docker, using docker-compose to manage all you docker stack related case.

Here is the sample code for my puckel/docker-airflow based airflow

```
version: '3'
```

services:
    postgres:
        image: 'postgres:12'
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        volumes:
            - ./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

```
webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - postgres
    environment:
        - LOAD_EX=n
        - EXECUTOR=Local
        - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgres://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    volumes:
        - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
```

To use it, You can

1- created a project folder. copy above reference code into

> docker-compose.yml

2- check if configuration is right by following docker-compose command

> docker-compose config

3- enabled the docker-compse project by:

> docker-compose up

Note: if you do not want to see detail logs, you can run it in backgroud by:

> docker-compose up -d

4. Now, you can enjoy airflow UI in you browser. by following url

> ```
> http://<the host ip>:8080
> ```

if you like above answer, pls vote it up.

Good luck
WY